# Display selected option in dropdown row when update in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Here I have codeigniter Update Code, it Almost worked but the problem is when i click Edit Button Didn't Fetch & Display selected option in drop down row.How Can I Solve this Error

**ViewIncome.php view Html**

```html
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-md" id="confirm-edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
<form class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Amount:</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="in_amnt" placeholder="amount">
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<label>Category:</label>  
<select class="form-control" id="in_cat">
<?php foreach ($income as $incm) {
?>
<tr>
<option value="<?php echo $incm->income_category_id; ?>"><?php echo $incm->category_name; ?></option>
</tr>
 <?php } ?>

</div> 
</div>

 
 <div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" id="btn-ys" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**ViewIncome_result.php view HTML**

```html
<table class="" dataTable"" id="income_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th ><center>AMOUNT</center></th>
<th ><center>CATEGORY</center></th>
<th ><center>EDIT</center></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach ($incm as $in_key) { ?>
<tr>
<td><center><?php echo $in_key->amount;?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $in_key->category;?></center></td>
<td>
<center><button type="button" title="edit" data-toggle="modal" edit_id=<?php echo $in_key->income_id;?>  in_amnt=<?php echo $in_key->amount; ?> in_cat=<?php echo $in_key->category;?> class="btn btn-info btn_edit" >  <i class="fa fa-pencil"> </i></button></center>              
</td> 
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

**ViewIncome.php view JavaScript**

```js
//edit data
$(document).on('click','.btn_edit', function(e) {  
$("#edit").val($(this).attr('e`enter code here`dit_id'));
$("#in_cat").val($(this).attr('in_cat'));
$("#in_amnt").val($(this).attr('in_amnt'));
$("#confirm-edit").modal({show:'true'});
});
   
$(document).on('click', '#btn-ys', function() {
var income_id = $('#edit').val();
var in_cat = $('#in_cat').val();
var in_amnt = $('#in_amnt').val();
                 
var result={"income_id":income_id,"in_amnt":in_amnt,"in_cat":in_cat};
       
$.ajax({
data:result,
type: "POST",
 url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/income/editincome/'+income_id,
success: function(data){    
$("#confirm-edit").modal('hide');  
viewData();
}
});
}); 
});
```

**Income.php Controllers**

```html
public function editincome($income_id)
{
$udata['income_id'] = $this->input->POST('income_id');
$udata['amount'] = $this->input->POST('in_amnt');
$udata['category'] = $this->input->POST('in_cat');
$update = $this->income_model->update_income_details($udata,$income_id);
}
```

**income_model.php Model**

```html
public function update_income_details($udata,$income_id)
{
 $this->db->from('income', $udata);
 $this->db->where('income_id',$income_id );
 return $this->db->update('income',$udata);
}
```

[The Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av0Ed.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC26G.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `selected="selected"` for displaying selected value! Please check below code :

```
 <select class="form-control" id="in_cat">
     <?php
     foreach ($income as $incm) {
     if ($incm->income_category_id == $in_cat) {
     ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $incm->income_category_id; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $incm->category_name; ?></option>
         <?php } else { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $incm->income_category_id; ?>"><?php echo $incm->category_name; ?></option>
         <?php
         }
     }
     ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: it's fetch only first option all of time, But I have Several Options are Selected in table So. When i click edit i want what i  selected in the options

Comment: Now  Error is (Message:  Undefined variable: in_cat) in if condition how can i solve @Nitin Vaghani