# How to make an option selected in dynamic dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter-3

I have a dynamic dropdown list of states. When I am selecting an option it is reloading another page, where I am displaying district belonging to that state. Now I want to do here after reloading the page of district I want to make the selected state display there in dropdown. I am unable to do that becasue it is dynamic

District page Code.

```
<option value=""><?php echo $state; ?></option>
                        <?php
                        if(!empty($stateNew)){
                            foreach($stateNew as $row){ 
                                echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo '<option value="">District not available</option>';
                        }
                        ?>  
                        </select>

                        <select id="state" class="bankSelect" name="state">
                        <option value="">Select District</option>
                        <?php
                        if(!empty($district)){
                            foreach($district as $row){ 
                                echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['district_name'].'</option>';
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo '<option value="">District not available</option>';
                        }
                        ?>                                  
                        </select>

                        <select id="city" class="bankSelect">
                                <option value="">Select district first</option>                                 
                        </select>
```

State page Code:

```
 <option value="">Select State</option>
                        <?php
                        if(!empty($state)){
                            foreach($state as $row){ 
                                echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>

                        <select id="state" class="bankSelect">
                                <option value="">Select state first</option>                                    
                        </select>

                        <select id="city" class="bankSelect">
                                <option value="">Select District first</option>                                 
                        </select>
```

All the values I am fetching from the database.

Comment: Set the value on the select? Use `$_GET` parameters to save the selection across refreshes?

Comment: That is fine, but then there I am getting duplicacy for selected state on another page when I am opening dropdown list. It is fetching all the state from database , showing it in dropdown list and in another option value I am trying to show the selected state. So there is a duplicacy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581713/display-selected-option-in-dropdown-row-when-update-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

To select an option dynamically, you need to set **selected** attritbute to *true* of option that you want to select like below

```
var state = document.getElementById("state");
state.options[STATE_INDEX].selected = true;
```

To get the index of state that you want to select, you can traverse through the options list and fetch the index of required state and then set its selected atttribute to true as above